# Create dictionary from txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have info contained in a archive called 'info.txt' and I want to import it to my script and from that info create dictionaries with the following sintax

```
{'UUU':'F', 'CUU':'L', 'AUU':'I'...}
```

I'm hardcoding the dictionary but I want to do it in a more clevere way. Snippet of my info saved in info.txt

```
UUU F      CUU L      AUU I      GUU V
UUC F      CUC L      AUC I      GUC V
UUA L      CUA L      AUA I      GUA V
UAA Stop   CAA Q      AAA K      GAA E
UAG Stop   CAG Q      AAG K      GAG E
UGU C      CGU R      AGU S      GGU G
UGC C      CGC R      AGC S      GGC G
UGA Stop   CGA R      AGA R      GGA G
UGG W      CGG R      AGG R      GGG G
```

How can I verify the tab spaces between tuples? How can I create my dict?

Comment: Have you looked at [Biopython](http://biopython.org)? It has DNA/RNA/protein translation tables already built in...

Comment: @MattDMo Looks awesome, Thanks for your suggestion. But in this case I need to code my own answer (educational purposes). I can code all the RNA codon table but I want to do it in a more clever way

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're reading from `info.txt` into one long string called `data`:

```
data = data.split()  # Splits into a list, delimiters are any kind of whitespace
keys = data[::2]
values = data[1::2]

result_dict = dict(zip(keys, values))
```